# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on NSURLSession on Simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, exc-bad-access, nsurlsession

I am pretty new to objective C. Started working with callbacks using NSURLSession. The application runs perfect on device.But the simulator gives some errors.

I am trying to do a POST and have a delegate which informs the caller when the response is received. I am able to get the expected data and it does not break my application. But, when I step through the instructions using the lldb debugger, it gives me a EXC BAD ACCESS and the error code changes for different simulators. This is the [instruction and error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDChr.png) on iPhone 5 simulator and this is the [instruction and error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Iq2Z.png) on iPhone 6 simulator.
Below is the code for the call back.

```
NSData *postData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dict options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];

[request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];

[request setHTTPBody:postData];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration]];

// Send the request to the server
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask=[session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){

    [self.delegate sendStatus:@"FetchCompleted!"];
}];

[dataTask resume];
```

My scheme is zombie enabled, and it did not log any zombie objects. I am pretty sure that the code above is the root cause of the error as I have tried to debug with commenting it and it works fine. Any help would be appreciated. Attached below below is the stack trace. Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean "step into the code"? Does the crash only happen when you're stepping through the debugger?

Comment: Yes, when I am stepping using the debugger, it throws EXC_BAD_ACCESS(code=1, address=0x1)

Comment: It throws this error in the lldb, and the line on which the error appears is:
0x5e273e <+16414>: xorb   %al, (%ebx)

Comment: What we need is the stacktrace.  When it crashes, go to the debugger console and type `bt` and post the results here.

Comment: Edited the question with the link for stack trace.

Comment: The error does not occur when I run and debug the app on iPhone. It looks strange, and I would appreciate if anybody could explain me what was going wrong. Thanks!